# Cannot convert const char to char

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, char

```
char messaggiou[100];    
char *name2;
string encoded;

name2 = (char*)malloc(encoded.length() + 1); 
strcpy(name2, messaggiou);                                     
strcpy(encoded.c_str(), name2);           
const char* hex_str = name2;
```

I get an error with this code (simplified), with vs2015 in C ++.

```
error C2664: `'char *strcpy(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'
```

P.s In messaggiou there is an encrypted string in hex

Comment: It looks like you are trying to copy `name2` into `encoded`. Since `encoded` is a string, you can acutally just use the `=` operator, and it will properly copy the data for you.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `strcpy` in C++?

Comment: You're misreading the error. You can convert `const char` to `char`. You cannot convert `const char*` to `char*`.

Comment: Funny, you say this is C++ but you're exclusively using the C language.

Answer (score 4):

if you use C++ I would do this in your place:

```
std::string messaggiou;    
std::string name2;
std::string encoded;

name2 = messaggiou;                                     
encoded = name2;          
const char* hex_str = name2.c_str();
```

Why complicate things if it can be easier, thanks to C++ :-)

You can also force any `const` with `const_cast<char*>(const object)`, but why if you don't need to...